# Zooming is not working after after Xcode 8 upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

I use Swift. `viewForZoomingInScrollView` is not working after upgraded my Xcode to version 8. My Zooming code was good working before the updated Xcode. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    /*ScrollView Zoom Code 01*/
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*ScrollView Zoom Code  02*/
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    /*ScrollView Zoom Code  03*/
     func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Xcode suggest new code but also it does not work zooming when I running on my iPhone:

[image: Xcode suggest new code but also it does not work zooming when I running on my iPhone]

Comment: Did you try with `func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?`

Comment: @Santosh Your code  is work thank you very much.

Comment: Great, mark my answer! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your method with `func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?`, should work with this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was very simple.